# Swift 2: Error: Initializer for conditional binding must have optional type, not 'CLPlacemark' in function Geocoder

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

I am creating a location based app where I want the user to be see details of their location. For showing their address details, I have added a new function, `CLGeocoder`, for finding the details. However, I get this error:

> Initializer for conditional binding must have optional type, not
>   'CLPlacemark'.

I get the error in:

```
if let p = CLPlacemark(placemark: placemarks![0] as! CLPlacemark )


CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation) { (placemarks, error) in

        if (error != nil) {
            print(error)
        }
        else {   
            if  let p = CLPlacemark(placemark: placemarks![0] as! CLPlacemark ) {
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: write let p = CLPlacemark(placemark: placemarks![0]) instead of 
if  let p = CLPlacemark(placemark: placemarks![0] as! CLPlacemark ) {
            }

Answer (score 0):

The expression inside the if-let needs to be optional. CLPlacemark initializer will never return an optional value. If you're unsure whether placemarks is nil or not, then something like

```
    if let placemarkArray = placemarks {
            let p = CLPlacemark(placemark: placemarkArray[0])
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
```

Otherwise, you don't need the `if let`...just `let`.

Comment: Is it giving you the same error, or a different one?

Comment: When I pasted the code, it asks me to to replace the question mark with exclamation mark. What should I do now?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood the code. I edited my answer.

Comment: It shows the same error for the second if statement you have added

Comment: Edited again, although I think @vadian's answer above is better

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create the `CLPlacemark` instance explicitly, `reverseGeocodeLocation` returns `[CLPlacemark]?` on success.

```
CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation) { (placemarks, error) in
    if error != nil { // no parentheses in Swift!
        print(error!)
    }
    else if let p = placemarks?.first {  
       // p is a non-optional CLPlacemark instance
       // Do stuff
    }
}
```